# Blazor: Wrap NavLink with List Item

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component

When I use a `NavLink` in a Blazor server application it gets rendered as `<a>`.
I would like to get a list item wrapping it such as `<li><a>`.

I also want to leverage as much as possible on the default behavior of `NavLink` (e.g. track active url).

I tried something simple like

```
public class ListItemNavLink : NavLink
{
    public string? ListItemCssClass { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "li");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", ListItemCssClass);

        builder.OpenElement(2, "a");

        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(3, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "class", CssClass);
        builder.AddContent(5, ChildContent);

        builder.CloseElement();
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

However when I try this

`<ListItemNavLink ListItemCssClass="sidebar-item" class="sidebar-link" href="x">`

I get this.

`<li><a listitemcssclass="sidebar-item" href="x" class="sidebar-link">`

Which is not exactly what I want. I would like to get something like this (please note the ACTIVE class state applied):

```
<li class="sitebar-item active">
<a class="sidebar-link">Some Text</a>
</li>
```

Any hint? Thanks

Comment: "Which is not exactly what I want."  What exact Html output are you expecting to get?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear. I added an example. Thank you

Comment: See mine or @enet answers below.  Two ways to the same end.  I use BuildRenderTree as enet has, but it's the equivalent of writing assembler.

Comment: @Shaun Curtis, the truth is that developers should use your version rather than mine...This has already been stated by Steve Anderson. My version is more difficult to write, error-prune, etc.

Comment: @enet - Ta, see you on the next question! Blazor Forum? Prune!

Comment: thanks a lot guys, I will follow your advice and take Shaun's answer :)

Comment: actually, any ways to include the active status in the `list item`? See in my example 

`<li class="sitebar-item active">`

Comment: I've included that in your control.  `ActiveClass` is the class the component uses when `NavLink`s gets a URL match.  By default it's *active*.  If it doesn't show then check the Match type.  Set `ActiveClass` to some other value and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood what you expect, try the following as your `ListItemNavLink` - ListItemNavLink.razor.cs.

```
<li class="@this.ListItemCssClass">
    <NavLink @attributes="@this.AdditionalAttributes" Match="@this.Match" ActiveClass="@this.ActiveClass" ></NavLink>
</li>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string ListItemCssClass { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public NavLinkMatch Match { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string ActiveClass { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

}
```

I've added the normal [Parameters] that you use with `NavLink` to your component so you can pass them through.

If you want to see how the `RenderTreeBuilder` contructs it find the *nnn.g.cs* file in  *obj/debug/net5.0/razor*